# F# Function doesn't let me mutate mutable value

Tags: function, variables, f#, mutable, mutation

Probably another dumb F# beginner's question... But it's bugging me all the same

I can't seem to find any answers to this online... might be 'cause I search the wrong terms but eh

anyway my code goes as follows:

```
let counter() = 
    let mutable x = 0

    let increment(y :int) =
        x <- x + y // this line is giving me trouble
        printfn "%A" x // and this one too

    increment // return the function
```

Visual Studio is telling me that `x` is used in an invalid way, that mutable variables can't be captured by closures

why is that? and what can I do to allow me to mutate it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As the error message indicates, you can use a `ref` cell instead:

```
let counter() = 
    let x = ref 0

    let increment(y :int) =
        x := !x + y // this line is giving me trouble
        printfn "%A" !x // and this one too

    increment // return the function
```

This does exactly what your code would do if it were legal.  The `!` operator gets the value out of the ref cell and `:=` assigns a new value.  As to why this is required, it's because the semantics of capturing a mutable value by a closure have proven to be confusing; using a `ref` cell makes things somewhat more explicit and less error-prone (see http://lorgonblog.wordpress.com/2008/11/12/on-lambdas-capture-and-mutability/ for further elaboration).

Comment: and what would that do? please explain in further detail I'm a complete noob at this language

Comment: @ElectricCoffee - I've added further explanation.  I have verified that my code works, so I'm surprised you're having trouble with it - are you sure you've removed your old code?

Comment: turned out I derped for a moment and forgot to remove `mutable` after applying your changes to my code... it works now thanks!

Comment: @ElectricCoffee I'm currently reading through Real World Functional Programming and the chapter I'm currently reading just covered that topic.  The book is excellent for those with C# experience who are learning F#. http://www.manning.com/petricek/